# Use bootstrap modal the same way as javascript alert() and confirm()

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I want to use bootstrap modal in all places where alert() and confirm() is used in my application. I found that bootbox is a good solution for this purpose. However it does not function the same way as native js functions. For example, it does not stop js code execution. I have to put all code in callback function if I need to wait for user click after opening modal.

Is there any way to create a javascript plugin like bootbox which can freely replace all places where confirm() is used without putting all functions that depend on result of user confirmation in callback.

Comment: No, this is not possible. Source: The many other SO answers to that question

Answer (score 0):

Then you can use this
https://github.com/sairam/bootstrap-prompts

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#alertMe').on('click', function(){
    alert("You are in an alert triggered by alert() javascript function");
  });
  $('#alertBrowser').on('click', function(){
    _originalAlert("You are in an alert triggered by original alert() javascript function");
  });
});
```

Comment: This implementation also uses the same concept as bootbox as it needs callback function in confirm(). Moreover, there is Big TODO in their README which says: Need to implement prompt() and confirm() actions so that they return